# why Magento2 serves LESS files when I'm in server-side-less-compilation modus?

Tags: magento2, server-setup, less, compilation

I have changed my admin-config LESS compilation modus to: Client side less compilation.
Now I have changed it back to: Server side less compilation.

But my admin panel and webstore still serve less files instead of css files...

I have tried:

- flush cache
- setup:di:compile
- rm -rf var/view_preprocessed

But nothing is working.

How can I get css files instead of less files?